# Save as Project vs. Save as Geopackage?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing

I have recently started at a company that uses QGIS for most of their mapping. The previous person in my position seemed to save all of their projects as one large geopackage. Our projects include several layer types, baselayers, themes, and layouts. I was taught to save my projects as a .QGS (QGIS Project). Obviously since this is what the company hasn't been doing there are questions about which is better. What are the main differences and why should we choose one over the other?

Comment: A project is not a container of data, but it contains layers order, styles, source paths etc., not data itself. GeoPackage is a database.

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz GPKG can also contain [QGIS projects](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/project_files.html#:~:text=implementations%20(PostgreSQL%20and-,GeoPackage,-).%20Clicking%20the%20action) https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Rjkq.png

Comment: @user2856 I didn’t know that. Thank you.

Comment: It looks like you are contrasting a project saved as a qgz separate from the geopackage containing the layers that are used in it, versus saving that same project within the geopackage itself.  I assume you did some searching on this.  I came up empty in mine. other than the potential advantage of having everything in one file.  You could of course do some of your own testing and see if there are any issues that come up or performance differences.  One question that comes to mind is whether you can still open that project in a text editor and troubleshoot that way.

Comment: The QGIS Project is stored as text (a HEX encoded zip file) in the `qgis_projects` table of the geopackage.

Comment: I think which is *better* is a bit subjective. It's essentially just a QGZ (zipped QGS + auxillary files) stored in a database (geopackage or PostgreSQL) instead of the filesystem.